# Calling function from external jsp on Click

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to run a function when I click on a button. 
The function is located in a js file that is located at another drive, I'm trying the following but when I'm clicking the button nothing happens.

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="file://E:/data/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>

<button onclick= "logOff()">logout</button>

<body>
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `src="file://E:/data/functions.js"` to `src="file:///E:/data/functions.js"`